# How to find the displacement vector between two points in a matrix?

Tags: matlab, vector

**Example:**

[image: example]

**Formula:**

[image: formula]

The difference between the two points gets the difference of the value of the received points of the matrix. If possible, could you suggest me a formula.

Comment: what does the matrix look like? Do you mean something like `M = [p1x, p1y; p2x, p2y]`?In this case, the vector for `p1` to `p2` is `M(2,:) - M(1,:)`

Comment: This is a image

Comment: What is an image? Can you be more specific? I understand you have a point `xi` and a point `xc`, so what is the difficulty in calculating `xi - xc`?

Comment: That's because it's an image, that's a matix. What I want is to find the place of the eye. Each point is a potential eye for me and I need to find the displacement vector everywhere

Comment: Hi @CBikmaz, I'm just wondering whether I have solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Minimum Distance between two points which are n-dimensional vectors in R^n can be found as below ( e.g: x= [ 1 3 5], y= [4 -4 7] 3-D points)

```
function result = minDistance (x, y) { 
 if ~isvector(x)
   error('Input must be a vector')
 result = sqrt(sum((x-y).^2))
end
```

if any additional information needed please explain the formula then solution can be fullfilled.

Comment: What you're saying is the difference between the two values. What I want is actually to create a vector there. I do not know how the formula works. There are only those that are written. It's just a displacement vector or displacement vector.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification, I think you only need a loop to do the job. The loop will go through each pixel, or point, in the picture, compare it with all other pixels and calculate the displacement vectors.

So for example, if you have a picture of 10x10, this means you have 100 pixels in the picture. For each pixel, you can calculate 99 displacement vectors. For the entire picture, you will have 99*100 displacement vectors.

```
% read your picture
im = imread('myImage.jpg');
imageSize = size(im);
xsize = imageSize(1);
ysize = imageSize(2);

% construct pixel matrix
pixelPosXM = repmat(1:xsize, ysize, 1);
pixelPosYM = repmat(1:ysize, 1, xsize);
% convert into array
pixelPosX = pixelPosXM(:);
pixelPosY = pixelPosYM(:);
nsize = length(pixelPosX);

for i = 1:nsize
    % construct matrix for calculation
    px = repmat([pixelPosX(i), pixelPosY(i)], nsize - 1, 1);
    otherPixels = [pixelPosX, pixelPosY]; otherPixels(i,:) = [];
    % calculate displacement vectors
    displacementVectors(:,:,i) = [px - otherPixels];
end
```

If you are not familiar with 3-dimentional matrix, you can replace

```
displacementVectors(:,:,i) = [px - otherPixels];
```

with

```
displacementVectors{i} = [px - otherPixels];
```

Comment: Thank you. You are very helpful